# Select table entry and use that for all subsequent queries in CAKEPHP 4 application

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I'm looking for the best approach for a workflow that I'm building for a Hockey Pool script written in CAKEPHP 4.x. To keep it simple, I have 3 tables (pools, players and teams). There can be multiple pools and each pool can have multiple teams. Those team then can have 1 or more players linked to them. I'm fine with all of the setup of the database and can create a functional site.

But what I want to do is have the user start with a pool. Then going forward when they add teams to that pool they are always adding players to that team (without having to select what team they are adding the team to).

My initial thought was to add the selected pool as query string so that as I move through the different components I would know what pool was initially selected. That works, but is not ideal as I have to ensure every link has that selected pool in the query string. My other thought was to store it as a cookie.

Thoughts?

Comment: Both of those solutions seem technically sound. The downside of the cookie version is that the user loses the ability to open two tabs to manage two different teams at the same time. This is why things like redirect URLs are most commonly passed as URL parameters now instead of stored in the user session.

Comment: Thank you Greg for the quick response. I plan on running this locally using phpdesktop so that prevents multiple tabs from being open at one time. Thanks again!!!